# From within a view, how can I determine which named url pattern led to the URL dispatcher calling that view?

Tags: django

I've got several named `url()`s in my URLConf that lead to the same view. From within that view, how can I find out which of these `url()`s matched and led to the view being called?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `request` object, which is the first positional argument of your view. It has a `request.path` attribute.

To find out how the resolver matched the current `request.path` against your URLConf, invoke the resolver:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
resolver_match = resolve(request.path)
```

Within a view, `resolver_match` is definitively guaranteed to be a `ResolverMatch` object, which contains a `url_name` property. This property is the name of the `url()` name that matched.

The `ResolverMatch` object has the following properties:

```
.app_name {str} or {NoneType}
.args {tuple}
.kwargs {dict}
.namespace {str}
.namespaces {list}
.url_name {str}
.view_name {str}
```